# How to populate SQL script in Spring Configuration to share across tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

I know `@Sql` can read an SQL script at the test class level or per test method, but I want to have this run in a `@Configuration` class, so that different test classes can simply `@Import` this config class and have the data inserted already BEFORE running any test method. Is this doable and how do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal with inheritance. Put the @Sql annotation in a base class and let you test classes extend it.

Sample code base class:

```
@DataJpaTest
@Sql(statements = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (NAME, EMAIL) VALUES ('John', 'john@mail.com');")
class DatabaseTestBase {
}
```

Sample test class:

```
class DatabaseTests extends DatabaseTestBase {

@Test
void checkSaveCustomer() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a workaround, but not exactly what I am after. The goal is to have the SQL loaded inside the common Configuration class so that the code is isolated from the test classes.